# Failed to get sum result of multiple asynchronous commands in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the result of multiple commands that run asynchronously, to far I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sum=0
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
     sum+=$(calculationCommand) &
done
wait

echo $sum
```

But it outputs 0 every time, can someone help me find the mistake and correct it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's ShellCheck:

```
Line 6:
     sum+=$(calculationCommand) &
     ^-- SC2030: Modification of sum is local (to subshell caused by backgrounding &).

Line 10:
echo $sum
     ^-- SC2031: sum was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.
```

You can not update variables from other processes. Instead, write the results to a file, `wait` for them to complete, and then read the data from the files.

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
calculationCommand() {
  sleep 5
  echo 2
}

for i in {1..10}
do
  calculationCommand > tmp.$i &
done
wait

sum=0
for number in $(cat tmp.{1..10})
do
  (( sum += number ))
done
echo "$sum"
```

Alternatives include using a fifo instead of 10 files.

Comment: Yeap, that was it, changed the code to write to file instead of memory, thanks!